# Skip the last data in a php if statement

Tags: php, skip

I want to print and add a character between them (e.g. *) if the id is a specific one (e.g. 3) but I don't want it to be added after the last data.

I have this code:

```
<?php 
foreach ($attribute_group['attribute'] as $attribute) {

if ($attribute_group['attribute_group_id'] == '3') {

    echo implode(' * ', $attribute['name'] . $attribute['text']);
    }

    else

    echo ($attribute['name'] . $attribute['text']);
    }
```

?>

The out put now comes as follows:

```
Attribute 1 * Attribute 2 * Attribute 3 *
```

I want it like:

```
Attribute 1 * Attribute 2 * Attribute 3
```

Comment: I don't understand. You're *also* adding a `*` between 1 and 2, even though you only specify 3? Do you just want to `implode()` these with a `*`?

Comment: The echo should only 'echo' when attribute_group_id is 3. And then not after the last record.

Comment: please paste the rest of your code; what is the origin of `Attribute 1, 2, 3`?

Comment: Have pasted the whole code above.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the last character:

```
$string = "Attribute 1 * Attribute 2 * Attribute 3 *";
echo rtrim($string, "*");
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can try like this by `rtrim()`:
Demo : https://eval.in/103723

```
$data =  array(
        '1' => 'Attribute 1',
        '2' => 'Attribute 2',
        '3' => 'Attribute 3',
        '4' => 'Attribute 4',
        '5' => 'Attribute 5'
    );

    $strOutput="";
    foreach ($data as $d){
     $strOutput .= $d." * ";

    } 

    echo rtrim($strOutput," * ");
```